# Let $T$ extend the theory of Groups. Prove there is a bound to the order.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, compactness

Let $T$ extend the theory of Groups. Suppose every element of every model of $T$ has a finite order. Show that there must be a bound to the order. Hint: Deny and run a Compactness argument to show a contradiction.

Anyone know how I can get started on this? The hints aren't really helping me.

Comment: Add to $T$ the axioms $A_n$, one for each natural number $n$, where $A_n$ says "there are at least $n$ distinct elements." Does the resulting theory have a model?  What about its finite subtheories?